# SQL Server stored procedure INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a stored procedure that should insert data into a table should that table exist. That portion of the code is in the `ELSE BEGIN ... END` statement. I get an error that the OBJECT already exists...

My code is like the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SYSOBJECTS 
              WHERE name = 'smsdss.c_order_utilization_lihn_svc_w_order_dept_desc_bench' 
                AND xtype = 'U')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.MY_TABLE ()
END
ELSE BEGIN
    DECLARE @TODAY_B DATE;
    DECLARE @START_B DATE;
    DECLARE @END_B   DATE;

    SET @TODAY_B = GETDATE();
    SET @START_B = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, @TODAY_B) -1, 0);
    BLAH BLAH BLAH

    INSERT INTO SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
        SELECT 
            COLUMN_A,
            COLUMN_B, 
            ..... ,
            COLUMN_N
        FROM 
            #TEMP_B
        WHERE 
            ORDER_YEAR > (SELECT MAX(ZZZ.ORDER_YEAR) FROM SCHEMA.MY_TABLE)
END
```

Comment: Please include the one line that contains the `IF` statement

Comment: The error indicates that the code is failing on the CREATE TABLE script (inside the IF block, not the ELSE). Likely your SELECT statement is incorrect.

Comment: IF the table exists it should be going to the else begin...no?

Comment: Try this instead and double check the schema and table name: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'smsdss' AND TABLE_NAME = 'c_order_utilization_lihn_svc_w_order_dept_desc_bench')`

Comment: ...found the error....its in my if statement. i took the schema out of the name parameter and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the code is failing on the `CREATE TABLE` script inside the `IF` block, **not** the `ELSE`. Likely your `SELECT` statement is incorrect.

You can fix that or try this instead and **double check the schema and table name**.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'smsdss' AND TABLE_NAME = 'c_order_utilization_lihn_svc_w_order_dept_desc_bench')
BEGIN
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[`OBJECT_ID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SCHEMA.MY_TABLE') IS NULL
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE ...
END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      INSERT ..
    END
```